# How to verify multiple checkboxes using php

Tags: php

I have a list which I am populating from my DB into multiple checkboxes using a `foreach` loop:

```
<?php 
$sections_arr = listAllForumBoards(0, 1, 100);
$count_board = count($sections_arr);
$ticker = 0;
foreach($sections_arr as $key => $printAllSections){
$ticker = $ticker + 1;
$sectionId = getBoardPart($printAllSections, 'id');
$sectionName = getBoardPart($printAllSections, 'title');
$sectionSlug = getBoardPart($printAllSections, 'slug');

?>
<dd><label for="<?php echo $sectionSlug; ?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="section[]" id="<?php echo $sectionSlug; ?>" value="<?php echo $sectionId; ?>" /> <?php echo $sectionName; ?></label></dd>
<?php } ?>
```

The list is populating as expected. But I want to be able to check to make sure that a user selects at least one of the checkboxes. I've searched here in SO and I only got the one that was done using [JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161741/how-to-check-multiple-checkboxes-checked-using-jquery), but I want to be able to do this verification using PHP

Comment: The only way you can do this purely in php would be AFTER the form is submitted, then it's just a matter of checking whether it's been set with `isset()` or `empty()`

Comment: So, doing `if(empty["section[]"])` will solve the problem OR is there a specific way to do this @Epodax ?

Comment: No, you have to do it after the form is submitted on your `$_POST` (Or `$_GET`), PHP cannot validate client side.

Comment: Exactly what I want to do (server side validation, just incase the user disables javascript in his/her browser). I understand that this will be done after the form is submitted, but my question is "how"? *Code snippets will be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: There are plenty of guides out there on how to do server side validation.

Comment: I understand that. I know how to do a server side validation for a single checkbox. What I want to achieve is how to validate for this kind of multiple checkbox which has the same `input name="sections[]"`.

Comment: Yes, and `empty()` does that. If no checkbox is selected then no value is sent, i.e it will be empty

Comment: Thanks. I've been able to get it done. I did `if(empty($_POST['sections])){
  // do something}`. I think the problem I was having was on how to call the input name, since it was having `sections[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file, where your form is submitting (action file) add this condition:

```
if (empty($_POST['section'])) {
    // it will go here, if no checkboxes were checked
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I've been able to rectify the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your action file, you should have the following

```
if(empty($_POST['section'])) {
    //this means that the user hasn't selected any checkbox, redirect to the previous page with error
}
```

Comment: Thank for your effort and editing. The issue has been resolved.